# LINQ find average from CSV objects

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I have a CSV with stock info in it (that I have a list of `DailyValues` objects called `stockValues`) that I need to pull from.  It looks like this:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2012-11-01,77.60,78.12,77.37,78.05,186200,78.05
2012-10-31,76.96,77.75,76.96,77.47,290700,77.47  //and so on
```

Essentially, I need to find the average volume for each year in the CSV with LINQ.  I can do it, but it's sloppy and only works for one year, so I'd have to copy the segment a bunch of times to do it for each year (it has years 1993-2012).  Here's what I have:

```
List<DailyValues> values2012 = stockValues.TakeWhile(n => n.Date.Year == 2012).ToList();
List<decimal> sum2012 = (from s in values2012
                         select s.Volume).ToList();
decimal average2012 = 0;
foreach(decimal el in sum2012)
{        
    average2012 += el;
}
average2012 /= sum2012.Count();

average2012 = decimal.Round(average, 2);

Console.WriteLine("2012 Average: " + average2012);
```

So, again, this works fine, but I don't want to have to do this for each year.  Does anyone know of a way to simplify my issue?

Comment: Why not simply pass a `Predicate<T>` to your `TakeWhile` clause? Each predicate can be of different year. Or do you really want to execute your method once for all years?

Comment: Do you want to get the average for all the years at the same time or just for a specific year?

Comment: I don't know what the `Predicate<T>` does so I'll have to look that up, but I do need to print a line stating the average of every year, if that answers your question.

Comment: @juharr print a line stating the average for each specific year yes.

Comment: The below answers should work for all dates.

Answer (score 3):

Can you  try something like:

```
 var groupedValues = stockValues.GroupBy(n => n.Date.Year)
                   .Select (g => new {
                       Average = g.Average(p => p.Volume), 
                       Year = g.Key
                    });
```

This will return average for each year, please see this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qKUKgh)

Comment: You don't need the anonymous class in the `GroupBy`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var groupedResults = stockValues.GroupBy(m => m.Date.Year)
                               .Select(g => new {
                                  year = g.Key,
                                  avg = g.Average(s => s.Volume)
                               });


foreach (var res in groupedResults)
   Console.WriteLine("{0} average : {1}", res.year, res.avg));
```

Comment: Should be `stockValues` instead of `values2013` as that variable is the one with all the values.